# How can I delete multiple lines in a php file

Tags: php, file

I really searched for that I want to do but I can't find it.

So basically I have a script that is supposed to delete an article and delete the abstract of that same article. All the abstracts of all articles are kept in the same file. This is the basic format of the file:

```
<!-- START article.html --><article id="class="post"><div id="post" class="post">
    <div class="posthead">
    <div class="dater">

    <p class="day"><a href="{$URL}article.html" >10</a></p>
    <p class="monthyear"><a href="{$URL}article.html" >May 14</a></p>
    </div>

        <h2><a href="{$URL}article.html"><span style="color: #2F64A4">article</span></a></h2></div>

        <div class="entry">
    Content summary here.
    <p style="text-align: justify;"> <a href="{$URL}article.html#more" class="more-link">Read further &raquo;</a></p>
                        </div>
        <!-- <p class="postmetadata"><span class="comm"><a href="{$URL}article.html#respond" title="Comments on article.">No comments yet.</a></span></p> -->
    </div>
```

So yeah all the abstracts are stored in this format in a single life (and all separated by a ). I'm trying to make a script that can delete the desired abstract but all I know I can do is to find the line which declares the beginning of the resumé and delete that line. I don't know how to delete the other lines until the end thing.

This is what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['file'])) {
foreach($_POST['file'] as $file) {
    if(isset($file)) {
        if (unlink('../content/'.$file.'')) {        //This line deletes the article

           //looking for deleting the abstract of the article
           $extrait = fopen('../content/extraits.html', "r+");
           if($extrait)
           {
              while(($ligne = fgets($extrait)) !== false)
              {
                if($ligne = '<!-- START '.$file.' -->)
               {     //delete here
                     //How do I delete the other lines that come after up until the <!-- END '.$file.' --> line?
               }
              }
           }
    }
echo "Deleted the file: $file<br />"; } else {
            echo "Didn't manage to delete the file: $file<br />";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S: If you could also light me to know what to do if I wanted to edit the abstract instead of deleting it (to make another function), that would be really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Search for *`<!-- END '.$file.' -->`*  in the line, and if it is not there, delete it.

```
$delete=false;
while(($ligne = fgets($extrait)) !== false){
    //TEST IF DELETING IS ON
    if($delete===true){
        //TEST IF <!-- END IS IN THIS LINE. IF NOT, DELETE THIS LINE
        if($strpos($ligne,'<!-- END '.$file.' -->')===false){
           //delete the line
           }
        //IF <!-- EN IS IN THIS LINE, DELETE AND STOP DELETING
        else{
           //delete this line
           $delete=false; //NOTHING MORE TO DELETE
           break;  //STOP SEARCHING
           }            
    //IF NOT YET DELETING, LOOK IF THE START OF THE ABSTRACT IS THERE AND START DELETING
    if($ligne = '<!-- START '.$file.' -->){
        //delete line here
        $delete=true;  //TURN DELETING ON
        }
    }
```

On a sidenote: this is typically done by using a database. if you can't, consider a more manageble way to store your data and using a template to show the html, in stead of storing the complete html.

If you store something like:

```
[*]filename 1|info 1|info 2|info 3
[*]filename 2|info 1|info 2|info 3
[*]filename 3|info 1|info 2|info 3
```

and keep all the data from one file on one line, you just have to delete this on line. In this way, you can also edit the information more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

It seems to work but can you also tell me how to delete the line? I thought a simple fseek() and a fwrite() would work but it seems it doesn't...

Comment: You can't just simply delete a line. You have to rewrite the file. take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461951/php-edit-delete-particular-line-in-a-file)